# GitHub Workflow Update Submodules to latest commits in Main Repo

Tags: github, yaml, github-actions, workflow, git-submodules

I have main repo that contains multiple submodules. Every time there's a change in a submodule, we have to open a PR in the main branch to update the submodule to the most recent change. I'd like to write a GitHub Workflow to do that automatically.

I found a workflow that can live in the submodule and when the submodule has a push to main, it automatically pushes the change to main on the Main Repo. But I can't seem to get it to work when incorporating the logic to check if a PR is open:
if so, push the update to that PR
if not, open a new PR
It always fails due to remote branch issues or local branch issues and asks about rebasing or ff.

The functioning workflow to auto push:

```
name: Send submodule updates to parent repo

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  update:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          repository: test/Test-Repo
          token: ${{ secrets.PAT_TOKEN }}
          ref: main
          submodules: true

      - name: Pull & update submodules recursively
        run: |
          git submodule update --init --recursive
          git submodule update --recursive --remote

      - name: Commit
        run: |
          git config user.email "actions@github.com"
          git config user.name "GitHub Actions - update submodules"
          git add --all
          git commit -m "Update submodules" || echo "No changes to commit"
          git push
```

Draft workflow that fails:

```
name: Send submodule updates to parent repo

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  update:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          repository: test/Test-Repo
          token: ${{ secrets.PAT_TOKEN }}
          ref: main
          submodules: true

      - name: Pull & update submodules recursively
        run: |
          git submodule update --init --recursive
          git submodule update --recursive --remote

      - name: Set up Git identity
        run: |
          git config user.email "actions@github.com"
          git config user.name "GitHub Actions - update submodules"

      - name: Determine if PR already exists
        id: check_pr
        run: |
          PR_EXISTING=$(curl -s -H "Authorization: Bearer ${{ secrets.PAT_TOKEN }}" \
            "https://api.github.com/repos/test/Test-Repo/pulls?state=open" | \
            jq '.[] | select(.head.ref == "update-submodules") | .number')

          if [ "$PR_EXISTING" != "null" ]; then
            echo "::set-output name=pr_number::$PR_EXISTING"
          fi

      - name: Checkout branch in main repo
        run: |
          BRANCH_NAME="update-submodules"
          git checkout -b $BRANCH_NAME

      - name: Commit and push changes in main repo
        run: |
          git add .
          git commit -m "Update submodule references to the latest main commits"
          if [ -z "${{ steps.check_pr.outputs.pr_number }}" ]; then
            # If no existing PR, open a new one
            git push origin $BRANCH_NAME
            curl -X POST \
              -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
              -H "Authorization: Bearer ${{ secrets.PAT_TOKEN }}" \
              https://api.github.com/repos/test/Test-Repo/pulls \
              -d "{\"title\":\"Update submodules\",\"head\":\"$BRANCH_NAME\",\"base\":\"main\"}"
          else
            # If existing PR, push to it
            PR_NUMBER="${{ steps.check_pr.outputs.pr_number }}"
            git push origin $BRANCH_NAME
            curl -X PATCH \
              -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
              -H "Authorization: Bearer ${{ secrets.PAT_TOKEN }}" \
              https://api.github.com/repos/test/Test-Repo/pulls/$PR_NUMBER \
              -d "{\"title\":\"Update submodules\",\"head\":\"$BRANCH_NAME\"}"
          fi
```

I'm new to workflows and don't know how to structure this. How do I handle merge conflicts? Should this logic live in the submodule or the main repo? Am I close with this logic or way off?

Comment: You might be able to get away without workflows by using dependabot to update the submodules. It [supports Git submodules](https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/dependabot/dependabot-version-updates/configuration-options-for-the-dependabot.yml-file#package-ecosystem), but isn't super flexible: you can't say "only update when there's a new release in the upstream repository". Instead, it'll open pull requests if there are any changes in the default branch, as far as I know. But it works well if that's good enough.

Comment: I use it to update my Vim plugins: with [this configuration](https://github.com/bewuethr/dotfiles/blob/main/.github/dependabot.yml), resulting in pull requests like [this one](https://github.com/bewuethr/dotfiles/pull/189).

Comment: I looked into the dependabot and wondered if there was any other way to trigger other than the interval: daily/weekly/monthly. Is there any alternative ways to trigger it?

Comment: You can manually trigger an update check by going to *Insights* > *Dependency graph* > *Dependabot* and clicking on "Recent update jobs".